# Tracking the times a string occurs in a file won't work after a loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, counter

I'm in an intro to CS class and I we have to pull strings from a file and print how many times that string is in the file. That part of it works fine. The problem is that we have to loop it to have it go through the same process for as many strings as they want. When I reset the variable counter that counts the amount of times the string is in the file to 0 the output says that variable is at 0. It is initialized at 0 so I do not see what changes after a loop.

```
while (answer) {
    int timesUsed = 0;  for (int i = 0; i < monAr.length; ++i) {
        while (monFile.hasNext()) {
            monAr[i] = monFile.next();

            if (monAr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(desiredTag)) {
                timesUsed = timesUsed + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("On Monday, #" + desiredTag + " appeared " + timesUsed + " times "+ "and was " + (((float) timesUsed / monAr.length) * 100) + "% of all hashtags used for the day."); 
    System.out.print("Do you want to search another hashtag (y/n)? ");
    choice = scnr.nextLine();

    if (choice.equals("n")) {
     answer = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `monFile`? It seems that you need to reset the reader that you have for that variable. Probably by instantiating that variable just below the `while` line

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should add that code. monFile is the variable that relates to the file being stored for Monday (there's one for every day of the week) it is Scanner monFile = new Scanner(new File("test/Monday")); IT WORKS THANK YOU

Comment: Try by adding that line just below the while(answer) line

Answer (score 0):

You can have another variable eg `totalUses` that will store the results of each iteration:

```
int totalUses = 0;
while (answer) {
    int timesUsed = 0;  
    for (int i = 0; i < monAr.length; ++i) {
        while (monFile.hasNext()) {
            monAr[i] = monFile.next();

            if (monAr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(desiredTag)) {
                timesUsed = timesUsed + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("On Monday, #" + desiredTag + " appeared " + timesUsed + " times "+ "and was " + (((float) timesUsed / monAr.length) * 100) + "% of all hashtags used for the day."); 
    System.out.print("Do you want to search another hashtag (y/n)? ");
    choice = scnr.nextLine();

    if (choice.equals("n")) {
     answer = false;
   }
   totalUses += timesUsed;
}
System.out.println("Total uses : "+ totalUses);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you’re using a `Scanner` to read your file, but if you need to re-scan, the pointer is already at the end of your file.

You need to instantiate your Scanner right below your `while` loop start:

```
Scanner monFile;
While(answer) {
    monFile = new Scanner(new File(“test/Monday”));
    ...
}
```